# PDO bindColumn and PDO::FETCH_BOUND -- compulsory or optional?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

In many places in our PHP code, (working with postgres if it matters)
we have stuff like:

```
$q  = "SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM alarms.current a, entities e, installations i ";
$q .= "WHERE i.\"entityId\"=e.id AND a.installationid=i.id AND ";
$q .= "e.id=".$entityId;

$stmt = $db->query($q);
$stmt->bindColumn("id", $alarmId);

if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
....etc
```

Now according to my reading of the docs, if you want your variables updated from their bound columns you ought to use PDO::FETCH_BOUND. But we don't, and no-one has complained about the performance as far as I'm aware.

Can anyone throw any light on why this apparently faulty code actually apparently works?

Answer (score 1):

While the example in the PHP documentation for `bindColumn` uses `PDO::FETCH_BOUND`, which does suggest that this fetch style is necessary in order to use `bindColumn`, it does not explicitly state that this is a requirement. It only says

> PDOStatement::bindColumn() arranges to have a particular variable bound to a given column in the result-set from a query. Each call to PDOStatement::fetch() or PDOStatement::fetchAll() will update all the variables that are bound to columns.

After some testing I determined that this will occur regardless of the fetch style that is used. I think the fact that the `fetch` call in your code is not actually fetched into a variable really just means that an associative array is created and assigned to nothing, while the side effect of the fetch populates the `$alarmId` variable.

Comment: Thanks - that is the only conclusion I can draw from the fact that 2 big applications of ours seem to do this "wrongly" and yet they work.

I would much prefer they were changed to do it "rightly", in case it turns out only to work this way with one database type, but I'll restrict myself to plastering the code with @FIXMEs for now.

Comment: Since the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is not actually fetched into anything, I can't imagine why changing it to `PDO::FETCH_BOUND` (which does look less confusing in my opinion) would cause any problems. I was actually using MySQL when I tested it with all different fetch styles, for what it's worth.

Comment: dont-panic - I have just realised there IS a situation where changing to FETCH_BOUND, as the documentation implies one should, will break my code.

Comment: @davidcollier That is interesting. Is that situation still using `if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` like in your question, or is it actually assigning, like `if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`?

Comment: Apparently I missed my chance to fix that - it should have read:  dont-panic - I have just realised there IS a situation where changing to FETCH_BOUND, as the documentation implies one should, will break my code.
The programmer had set up a bunch of bindParams, but was then using the return values from a FETCH_ASSOC style to decide whether there was data to process.
Fixing it to use FETCH_BOUND would force the return value to TRUE, which would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Apparently I can't format code snippts in here, but   $installations->bindColumn("schemaName", $schemaName);
    $installations->bindColumn("entityId", $entityId);
    
    while($installations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

Comment: So when using `FETCH_BOUND`, it returns `true` even when it reaches the end of the result set? That seems strange. I didn't mean to sound like I don't believe you. It's just not how I would have expected it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @DontPanic's comments, here is how I prefer to use bound parameters:

```
/**
* @param $id
*
* @return array|false
*/
public function retrieveImage($id)
{
    $conn = $this->dbh->getInstance('LocalMSSQL');
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT inputType, blob FROM images WHERE id = ?");

    $stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $resultSet = [
        'inputType' => null,
        'blob' => null,
    ];

    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $resultSet['inputType'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindColumn(2, $resultSet['blob'], PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);

    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        return $resultSet;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```