# Does data fetched from a PDO statement consume memory if it is not assigned to a variable?

Tags: php, pdo

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438490/pdo-bindcolumn-and-pdofetch-bound-compulsory-or-optional), which uses the following code:

```
...
$stmt->bindColumn("id", $alarmId);
if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
...
```

After experimenting with it, I learned that while `PDO::FETCH_BOUND` is used in the example in the PHP documentation, `bindColumn` apparently works regardless of the fetch style that is used, so it looks like `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is pointless here because it isn't assigned to a variable.

But this makes me wonder, what is the effect of fetching with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` without actually assigning the result to anything? (I understand that the use of `bindColumn` means that part of the result IS actually assigned to `$alarmId` in this example, but I'm interested in what happens to the ephemeral associative array.) Does it temporarily exist in memory even if it is not assigned to a variable, or does PHP just ignore it if there is no assignment? Is there a way I could test this?

Comment: I'm also aware that the amount of memory in question is negligible. I don't intend this to be a performance question. I'm really just more curious how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::fetch` returns a cursor pointing to the next item in the result set, which contains a kind of a `generator` allowing you to iterate over the result set one item at a time.
`PDO::fetchAll` returns the data set in a numeric \ associative array depending on the fetch mode that you have selected, and this consumes the memory that is required to store the entire result set.